# Which way to calculate expectation is correct?

Tags: probability

Might be a stupid question, but I really got stuck. Suppose, there is some ex-ante unknown amount of money $c$ in your pocket. It is drawn from some distribution $F$ over $[0,N]$. If the amount appears to be less then some $K<N$, you have to pay all this amount. If it is above, you pay nothing. What is your expected payment?

Option 1: $\int_0^{K}\!c\, \mathrm{d} F(c)$
Option 2: $F(k)\int_0^{K}\!c\, \mathrm{d} F(c)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What the two options give if the distribution was uniform, $N=4$ and $K=2$?

Comment: I indeed tried. Reasoning says Opt 2, though intuitively it feels like some kind of double counting.

Comment: Why does reasoning suggest Option 2?  What do the two options give if the distribution was uniform, $N=4$ and $K=2$?

Comment: 1 and 0.5. Opt2: Expected amount is $\int_0^{K}\!c\, \mathrm{d} F(c)$, but the prob that I will pay it is $F(K)$.

Comment: You might want to check your calculations: I get $\frac12$ and $\frac14$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is double counting and wrong.

Meanwhile $\displaystyle \frac{1}{F(K)}\int_0^{K}\!c\, \mathrm{d} F(c)$ would be the conditional expectation of the amount you have to pay given that $K \lt c$, i.e. given that you have to pay anything.